# QWebPage and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qwebkit, qwebpage

I have this code:

```
class TestThread : public QThread
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        QFile file("test.html");
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        QWebPage page;
        page.mainFrame()->setHtml(file.readAll());
        qDebug() << page.mainFrame()->toHtml();
        qDebug() << "\n\n\n\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        TestThread thread;
        thread.start();
        thread.wait();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

And output:

```
"<html><head>
    <title>My page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        My content

</body></html>" 





"<html><head></head><body><html>
  <head>
    <title>My page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        My content
  </body>
</html></body></html>"
```

In the second pass, there are too many tags. What is workaround? Or where is my mistake?

Comment: Please post the contents of test.html as well.

Comment: there's a third html being written somewhere between the two you actually want.

Comment: I cannot to edit my post. I get the message: "Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly." :-(

Comment: May be file is not closed.  Just a wild guess...

Comment: No, file does not play any roles. The issue in the threads!

Comment: If i call frame->setHtml("") i get the content with superfluous tags: "<html><head></head><body></body></html>"

Comment: Just in case ... you could try filesystem locks

Comment: You're trying to open a file that has been already opened, you do know that right? Cause you're not closing it at all.

Comment: I compiled this: http://pastebin.com/93LXx76k and i got it alright.

Comment: Are you sure you want sethtml? Maybe what you want is setcontent function?

Comment: **The text in setHtml is correct**. This code is just example, my real project use other way to posting content to QWebPage.

Comment: With setContent I have the same issue

Comment: @Patrick Bassut: The file is closed by the QFile destructor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue in the Linux OS. In Windows I got the message "Widgets must be created in GUI thread". But the content in the QWebPage is correct. So, I will not be used QWebPage for my task.